# Plotting squares of colored pixels from the Gaussian distribution

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, grid, lattice

I would like to generate an image like this:

[image]

where the pixel colors are determined by the value of the multivariate normal distribution. In other words, I have the following dataframe:

```
images <- data.frame(x = rnorm(256*256*20), image = rep(c(1:20), each = 256*256))
```

And I would like to plot each of the 20 vectors of draws from the multivariate normal, as colored squares. The squares should be aligned on a 2x10 grid. It doesn't matter if they are separated by black lines or not, but there must be some kind of separation between different squares. The value 0 should correspond to a grayish or white color (grey would be better). How can I do that? I would like a `ggplot` solution, but base R or something else is good too, as long as the code is reasonably flexible and readable (performance is not an issue).

**EDIT** the squares don't have to be 256*256, 64*64 would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt:

generate r, g, b channels:

```
library(tidyverse)

images <- data.frame(r = rnorm(256*256*20),
                     g = rnorm(256*256*20),
                     b = rnorm(256*256*20),
                     image = rep(c(1:20), each = 256*256))
```

function to convert rgb to hex:

```
rgb2hex <- function(r,g,b) rgb(r, g, b, maxColorValue = 255)
```

convert the `rnorm` with 0 mean and 1 sd to r, g, b channels by rescaling to 0-1 range and multiplying by 255 and finally converting to hex

```
images %>%
  group_by(image) %>%
  mutate(y = rep(1:256, each = 256), #x coords
         x = rep(1:256, times = 256), #y coords
         r = round(scales::rescale(r) * 255, 0), 
         g = round(scales::rescale(g) * 255, 0),
         b = round(scales::rescale(b) * 255, 0), 
         hex = rgb2hex(r, g, b)) -> for_plot

  ggplot(for_plot) +
       geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y), fill = for_plot$hex)+
       facet_wrap(~image, ncol = 10) + 
       coord_equal()
```

[image]

Simplification:

```
rgb2hex <- function(r,g,b) rgb(r, g, b, maxColorValue = 1)

images %>%
  group_by(image) %>%
  mutate(y = rep(1:256, each = 256),
         x = rep(1:256, times = 256),
         r = scales::rescale(r),
         g = scales::rescale(g),
         b = scales::rescale(b), 
         hex = rgb2hex(r, g, b)) -> for_plot
```

EDIT: DeltaIV requested clipping the darker tones in the comments here is an approach:

```
n = 0.2

images %>%
  group_by(image) %>%
  mutate(y = rep(1:256, each = 256),
         x = rep(1:256, times = 256),
         r = scales::rescale(r) + n,
         g = scales::rescale(g) + n,
         b = scales::rescale(b) + n, 
         hex = rgb(r, g, b, maxColorValue = 1 + n)) -> for_plot

ggplot(for_plot) +
  geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y), fill = for_plot$hex)+
  facet_wrap(~image, ncol = 10) + 
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

increasing n = 0.5 results in lighter images

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work. `> ggplot(for_plot) +
+     geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y), fill = for_plot$hex)+
+     facet_wrap(~image, ncol = 10) + 
+     coord_equal()
Error in ggplot(for_plot) : object 'for_plot' not found`

Comment: The actual error is upstream: `> images %>%
+     group_by(image) %>%
+     mutate(y = rep(1:256, each = 256), #x coords
+            x = rep(1:256, times = 256), #y coords
+            r = round(scales::rescale(r) * 255, 0), 
+            g = round(scales::rescale(g) * 255, 0),
+            b = round(scales::rescale(b) * 255, 0), 
+            hex = rgb2hex(r, g, b)) -> for_plot
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: color intensity 93, not in [0,1].` Can you fix your code?

Comment: Also, while you're at it, would it be possible to make it so that the random square corresponding to all zeros is gray? Your code would make it black. Right?

Comment: @DeltaIV check edit on clipping. Similarly one could clip the upper side of the range as well